# Double click a particular cell and hit enter

Tags: vba, excel

What would be the code to double click a particular cell and then hit enter (this triggers updates to other cells but it is not important for this query)?

I've created something like that but I can't even get it to run (it doesn't appear in my "View Macros" window).

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
 With Worksheets("Input")
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J3")) Is Nothing Then
      Range("J3").Value = Range("J3").Value
      Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: because its Private, because its an event, because you need to study alot more.......

Comment: Ok, I see, is there a way to activate a cell (double click) and hit enter to update it by using a macro?

Comment: `Cells(1,1)="Hello"`... does the same

Comment: `Range("J3").Value = Range("J3").Value` will just replace its own value. This method is frequently used to mimic paste as value.

Comment: So in my case it is cell J3 in an "Input" worksheet, so would it be  Sheets("Input").Range("J3").Value=Sheets("Input").Range("J3").Value ?

Comment: Is this a round-about way to do the same thing that `Application.Calculate` does?  When you say "this triggers updates to other cells ..." it sounds like you just want to trigger a recalculation, which is what `Application.Calculate` does.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I have Private Sub Worksheet_Change macro as well, and if I don't refresh this particular cell (J3) this will not trigger some changes to other cells as part of the Change macro.Therefore I need to double click it and press enter. 

The reason I want to do it is that when I sort the master data, the row number (which the Private Sub Worksheet_Change calculates in a different cell) does not recalculate unless I activate the J3 cell. Therefore I need J3 to be activated. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: One way to refactor your code is to write a sub that contains the bulk of the code that you currently have in `Worksheet_Change` and then degrade `Worksheet_Change` to little more than a caller of this new sub. If you need this sub to run without a change event -- just call it directly without the kludge of artificially triggering a dummy change.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still new to macros. Would it help if I paste the code below (I highlighted the moment when I need to activate cell J3): https://jpst.it/Rsj_
(the code was too long to paste so I used a link where the code is presented)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub
```

But the code must go in the proper place.  Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: How do I point out which cell it should address? I'd like this macro to be part of my existing macro, so that the action takes place in the appropriate point.

Comment: @ewuchatka The macro can work with any cell... `Target` is the cell that was double-clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem today (though it was slightly different in that the results of a SQL query had an Excel formula as one of the fields which wouldn't auto-calculate, it just left the text of the formula).  The way I was able to resolve it was:

```
Range("J3").Formula2R1C1 = Range("J3").Formula2R1C1
```

It just sets the Formula back to itself, but in my situation it would evaluate the formula, which wasn't happening with any other solution I tried.